# Active sync based Enterprise application on Android/IPhone platform

Tags: android, iphone, web-services, exchange-server

I am trying to create a Mobile Application which can give me access to Calendar, Schedules, Email and other features of a Exchange Account.

Can this be done using Active Sync? Can anyone please provide me some links of tutorials/examples sort on the same?

This is to be implemented on both Android and IPhone platform.

I have searched across, but i haven't gotten a clear answer.

Also i have a limitation that i cannot make changes to the exchange server configuration, since it will be a very high level business decision.

Let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Android, Google has provided support for enterprise application through Device Policy management. Support for exchange email was introduced in early versions of Android (1.6) and support for calendar and event integration was added later in subsequent releases. Please visit this document for more information:
http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//events/io/2011/static/presofiles/taking_android_to_work.pdf